# Doctrine wildcard WHERE query?

Tags: database, symfony1, doctrine

Is it possible to craft a wildcard WHERE query with Doctrine, like so:

```
->where('this_field = ?', ANYTHING);
```

I'd be using this to build a search query dynamically out of unknown user-selected parameters and therefore would need to have the condition in place but capable of accepting the value "anything".

To add, I can get this to work:

```
$field = 'this_field = ?';
$value = 5;
...
->where($field, $value);
```

... but it's still doesn't allow me to use "anything" as value or to eliminate the entire query condition. The following fails:

```
$field = NULL;
$value = NULL;
...
->where($field, $value);
```

Thanks

Comment: I suspect there's a better way to solve your problem. Additionally allowing the user to specify a where clause is probably a security no-no.

Comment: Thanks - not allowing users to do that but just need to process lots of optional dropdown values. Any thoughts on what that better way might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you build the query dynamically you can also check wther `$value` has a value or not and then add the where part if necessary. E.g.

```
$q; // Your query object.

if(isset($value)) {   // or empty() or maybe just if($value) depending on your needs.
    $q->where('this_field = ?', $value);
}
```

This is easier to understand and easier to debug imo.

Comment: Felix, ah yes indeed, that's the way to do it. Manipulating the query object is the easiest for building it dynamically. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Answer to own question]

After playing around with this, found a solution that works, posting here for others.

Using `->whereIn` allows Doctrine to ignore a query condition completely:

```
$empty = array();
...
->andWhereIn('this_field', $empty)
```

The above condition doesn't get included in the resulting SQL at all.